# How to use material design icons in nuxt

Tags: material-design, mdi

From like hour ago I keep getting network error on material design icons cdn as error name not resolved.

http://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/5.4.55/css/materialdesignicons.min.css

I am wondering why is nuxt app using cdn instead of downloaded files?

When I try to run `npm install nuxt-material-design-icons` or `npm install material-design-icons` it just freezes..

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out,

**Step 1:** Add Google fonts icon's CDN.

```
export default {
  head () {
    return {
      link: [
        // Add this
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' }
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 2:** Use it (you are done!)

```
<template>
  // Add this
  <span class="material-icons">face</span>
</template>
```

[Here](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons) is the complete list of Material Icons.

Answer (score 2):

For Nuxt.js, you will need to install [this package:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-material-design-icons-iconfont)

```
yarn add nuxt-material-design-icons-iconfont
// Or if you are using npm:
npm install nuxt-material-design-icons-iconfont
```

And declare that package within **nuxt.config.js** file:

```
modules: [
  'nuxt-material-design-icons-iconfont',
],
```

Comment: This package does not support nuxt3

Comment: There is a long list of Nuxt3 incompatible modules: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/751

Answer (score 0):

Add "nuxt-material-design-icons" in "modules" in nuxt.config.js

Answer (score 0):

update for nuxt 3 users:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    head: {
      link: [
        // Include Google Fonts Material Icons CDN
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' },
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0' },
        // ...other link tags
      ],
    },
  },
})
```